# Simulate a web page without displaying it

Tags: javascript, php, html, web

I have an HTML page with a button that when pressed download a file.
I need to create a new website that will include the possibility to download that file and I would like to use the first page to do that.
In other way I would like to make the new website to load the first HTML page without displaying it and use it only to download the file, emulating the button pressed.

The only way that comes to my mind is parsing the HTML page and discover where the file is located and then download it. Are there other way to do the same in PHP? And in Javascript?

Comment: Why do you need to involve the first page at all instead of just going to the URL of the download?

Comment: because I don't know the URL, that is embedded in the HTML page

Comment: Why not? Does it change? If it does are you trying to bypass a security mechanism on the other site? Since that would be illegal in some places.

Comment: Yes, it could change. Why do you think it can bypass a security mechanism? The HTML page is public, so everything can be done by the user (button click and then file download) should also be done by my website (file download)

Comment: One reason for changing a URL is to make it harder for automated downloaders to get the data so that people are forced to look at the page and see adverts.

Comment: I understand. My case is very different: the file is updated constantly with new versions by some people while the website will be managed by people from a different group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I would strongly urge *against* doing it, because it is much simpler to just go directly to the URL, if you need tools that can parse an html-page, perform actions on it, and do something with the results of those actions, you are in luck.

There is an entire suite of tools devoted to this purpose, namely those used by web application testers.

Check out Selenium as an example:

http://docs.seleniumhq.org/

It lets you configure "test scenarios" which can very easily download a page, search for a button, click that button, download the resulting file, and then do whatever else is needed. And since it's designed as a testing tool, it has *very* good built-in support for handling any steps failing ;)

There are many more of these tools; if you look up "automated browser testing" you'll probably find plenty, in all sorts of languages.

Comment: Thanks @Erik for providing this useful comparison with testing. I didn't think of my issue as a testing function, but it actually resembles it.  I'll give a look at Selenium